# How to get number of live viewers?

Tags: php, jquery

I currently have PHP + jQuery script that shows number of live viewers, but it doesn't really show the correct number, because it's based on IP. For example, when there are multiple devices (with same page opened) with same "home" internet, then it would show only 1 live viewer (all requests contains same IP). Does anyone have any better idea? Also, would be nice if someone can tell how it can be optimized.

jQuery script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var count = $('.viewers');
        count.load('viewers.php');
        setInterval(function(){
                count.load('viewers.php');
        }, 1000)
});
```

PHP script

```
<?php
$watcherIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$intIP = ip2long($watcherIP);

try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$databaseServer;dbname=$databaseName", $databaseUsername, $databasePassword);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM gnt_watchers WHERE ip=:ip LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute(array(':ip' => $intIP));
        $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        if ($result) {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE gnt_watchers SET dt=NOW() WHERE ip=:ip");
                $stmt->execute(array(':ip' => $intIP));
        } else {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO gnt_watchers (ip) VALUES (:ip)");
                $stmt->execute(array(':ip' => $intIP));
        }

        $conn->query("DELETE FROM gnt_watchers WHERE dt<SUBTIME(NOW(), '0 0:0:10')");

        $totalOnline = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gnt_watchers")->fetchColumn();
        echo $totalOnline;
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Comment: It should be session based not IP based.

Comment: I agree, you need to use sessions / cookies.

Comment: Re your edit: if that's a working script, post it as an Answer, below (you are allowed, and encouraged, to answer your own questions). It makes no sense to include it in the Question area, because it's part of the solution, not part of the problem! And if you add it separately as an answer below, people can upvote it if they like it :-). This is a Q&A site...in each post there's a section for the question, and a separate section for the answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

Modified script from IP to session based. But there's still one thing - when you have multiple tabs opened, then all of them have same session... so it doesn't still give exact number of live viewers. No idea how's about cookie, have to explore.

PHP script

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["sIDv"])) {
        // Unique Session ID exists!
} else {
        $_SESSION["sIDv"] = md5(uniqid());
}

$viewerIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$databaseServer;dbname=$databaseName", $databaseUsername, $databasePassword);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM gnt_viewers WHERE session=:session LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute(array(':session' => $_SESSION["sIDv"]));
        $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        if ($result) {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE gnt_viewers SET timestamp = NOW() WHERE session=:session");
                $stmt->execute(array(':session' => $_SESSION["sIDv"]));
        } else {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO gnt_viewers (session, ip) VALUES (:session, :ip)");
                $stmt->execute(array(
                        ':session' => $_SESSION["sIDv"],
                        ':ip' => $viewerIP
                ));

        }

        $conn->query("DELETE FROM gnt_viewers WHERE timestamp < SUBTIME(NOW(), '0 0:0:10')");

        $totalOnline = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gnt_viewers")->fetchColumn();
        echo $totalOnline;
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
        //throw $e;
        echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```